# SugarCRM doesn't work on live server but work good on local

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm using sugarCRM version 6.5.20 which was installed on staging server (Linux) and my local machine (Windown 10) and it works just great but on the live server (Linux) the label missing, sometime label display well but when I refresh page it disappear again. Sometime the tab People and Companies are broken that it doesn't load anything and display error code  500 server.
I have read many guide to fix the error but it doesn't work. Someone please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you very much for any helps. (Sorry for my bad English).
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the permission? if not refer : http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/Platform_Management/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux/

Comment: Hi @sAcH, I have followed that refer before but it doesn't work. Now I have set permission to 777 for all files and folders but :(

Comment: Do one thing. Go to admin=>studio=>your module=>fields and check the which field labels are missing and update the missing labels with the actual name. save it and reload the cache and check

Comment: @sAcH Nothing wrong and on staging server and my local it works just fine. On live server the labels display just for a while and when I refresh page it gone.

Comment: Have you tried with keeping developer mode off?

Comment: Yes @sAcH, `$sugar_config['developerMode'] = false;` . There is only one message I found on log file is **Tue May 17 08:04:52 2016 [13481][1][FATAL] Error: Module app_strings does not exist.**

Comment: this is the problem with the language file, first try to repair and rebuild your application to rebuild the cache

Answer (score 0):

Reason to Not working Sugar on server and it is working on local.

1. Language file
   please check language files are available on server with your changes.
2. Check metadata date on local and serve it may be chance some fields are not available on server it happens commonly.
3. Developer mode should be off on server otherwise it will slow down your website.
4. It may happen some drop down will not work on server try to make collect all drop down code in a single file , it helped me.to show drop down.
5. Try to give permission to cache file and another files also , some time it cause permission problem, you code on window os in local but server is unix based so you need to give proper permission on server .

From my side these are the reasons , on server . And i think you will found the solution between above reasons only.